# Load datagrid using a PHP OOP method?

Tags: php

I am try to use the example given in "[Build CRUD Application with jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud.php)",
but this time round I have a PHP OOP function called `get_users`:

```
public function get_users() {

$rs = mysql_query("select * from users");

$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($result);
}
```

How do I call the function at `<table url="?????">`?

```
table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
        url="<?php  $company->get_users(); ?>"
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up php and Javascript. PHP Runs on the server and generates the html and javascript you want.

Javascript can be run on the client as you are indicating.

perhaps it should look like this

```
<table id="dg" title="My Users" 
    class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
    url="http://me.example.com/path/to/company_get_users.php"
```

Comment: ok lemmie clarify comapny.php is the file that contains the method get_users() and this method is what I want to populate the datagrid since if i put url='company.php' it's not populating the datagrid.

Comment: this is the company.php file <?php 
include_once 'config/config.php';


class Company{
 
  public $arry_data = array();
  
      //Database connect 
 public function __construct() 
    {
      $db = new DB_Class;

}

 public function get_users() {

  $rs = mysql_query("select * from users");
 
 $items = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
  array_push($items, $row);
 }
 $result["rows"] = $items;

 echo json_encode($result);
 }
}
 ?>